ARIMA Models Modifications
I'm current working on a project. This project specify in using ARIMA Models to predict the future value of variable 'cases'. After differencing the time-series to make it stationary, here is the graph of ACF and PACF


I'm struggling to choose the ARIMA models for this time-series. What do you guys think the ARIMA models should be based on those graphs.
